# I need to install Tensor Flow 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

Goal: I need to install Tensorflow 1 in order to use Object Detection.

I have tried to look online for an answer I couldn't find.

I have python version 3.8.5 64 bit.

I have also tried pip install tensorflow==1.15. As shown in the Docs:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

This is what command prompt shows:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15

Why can't I do "pip install tensorflow 1.15"?

Comment: Add your logs from console, please. Now we now nothing about problem.

Comment: These are my logs: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15

Comment: Did you try suggestions in [that](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34302) issue?

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure what 2.2.0rc1 means.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question. The reason why it did not work till now because I was using python 3.8. But when I was using 3.7 it did work.

Comment: That issue was in my link. Could you set my answer as accepted?

Comment: @M. Dudek sure, but to accept it, you must write it as an answer. Unfortunately, I can't accept comments.